# maximum RAM avaiable for an asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, iis

If I buy a server on which I'll be able to put as much RAM as I want, how much RAM can I make available for my asp.net web app using the latest versions of everything?

Reason I'm asking is that I plan to use InProc session to its full potential.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any process on a 32-bit Windows Server is limited to 2GB unless you have set the /3GB switch in your `boot.ini` file, in which case a process can use 3GB.

If you're using a 64-bit server you will be limited by what the server can offer.
See [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You may also need to [increase the Max memory the application pool in IIS can use](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732519%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Also see [the maximum memory allowed for w3wp worker processes on 64-bit IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631902/what-is-the-maximum-memory-allowed-for-w3wp-worker-process-on-64-bit-iis-7).

Are expecting a heavy load on the server? Had you thought about using the database to store sessions, or MVC .Net with no session state?

Comment: I was asking because I'm considering using InProc session, at least initially.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the memory to 6 GB or more on the server  won't help because 4 GB is the
maximum for addressable memory for Win-32. You would have to go to Win 64 in
order to add more memory to the server configuration.

If its a dedicated is box, you can try running with the 3GB switch,
which would allow the asp.net to use up to 3GB.

You should also check what your current max memory is set to...!?